# CGContext Delete Path

Tags: ios, xcode

How do I remove a path when the path with different color draws on the top of that previous path using CGContext?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGContextBeginPath()` always throws away the previous path in the process of creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am using kCGBlendModeDarken to achieve transparent effect. I am getting this result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UroVd.png

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "remove a path"...based on your picture are you trying to get rid of one of the lines and not all of them?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Tell me how can i achieve this effect ?

Comment: Based on provided picture, when i draw red line over other lines it also shows the color of other lines at the point of intersection. I want to show only red color at the point of intersection.

Comment: That blending/darkening is what `kCGBlendModeDarken` does.  You'd have to choose a different mode (like `kCGBlendModeNormal`) to have the line drawn opaquely.  Also note that transparency effects can be achieved by setting the alpha channels of colors themselves.

Comment: Okay, but when i reduce the alpha of lines, i get this effect: http://i.imgur.com/f2Oxr.png

Comment: Hey Kevin, actually i want to create every context on the same layer. Because i have noticed when i switch color, it draws lines on the other layer.

Comment: If `CGContextStrokePath()` is used to render all lines at once, do they still darken at the overlap points?  If so, you may need to render the lines opaquely in one location (e.g. a `CGLayerRef` that combines all the lines on a neutral background) and then draw the layer all at once in a darkening mode over the image.  I have not tried that but it should work.